# Docker: Mount directory from one container to another

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have two docker images. One of the docker image (from first container), when ran, generates some files, which needs to be consumed by the another container.

Can I do this?

Comment: Did you get solution for this issue? I have the same question.

Answer (score 31):

Rene's answer works, but you could share data without using the host's directory (container1 ==> container2):

```
docker run -v /data/myfolder --name container1 image-name-1
docker run --volumes-from container1 image-name-2
```

Comment: Hi @Manuel,  Thanks for your answer. Could you please elaborate how will I access those file inside container2?

Comment: Just an update Manuel. I tried this out and this works great! But the problem it's mounting at the same location as source container. Can I mount it at some point else?

Comment: Hi, that's not supported, There was [a proposal related to that](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/11261) but at this moment it's not possible to change the location of the mount point.

Answer (score 18):

Oracle had a an example on their website in 2015 (which is not available any more). Based on this i created

https://github.com/BITPlan/docker-stackoverflowanswers/tree/master/33232991

**Dockerfile.data**

```
# Dockerfile that modifies ubuntu to create a data volume container
FROM ubuntu:14.04
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html
RUN echo "This is the content for file1.html" > /var/www/html/file1.html
RUN echo "This is the content for file2.html" > /var/www/html/file2.html
RUN echo "This is the content for index.html" > /var/www/html/index.html
VOLUME /var/www/html
ENTRYPOINT /usr/bin/tail -f /dev/null
```

for the data image and

**Dockerfile**

```
# Ubuntu image
FROM ubuntu:14.04
```

for the image to test the use of the other data only volume.

```
docker build -t bitplan/dataonly:0.0.1 -f Dockerfile.data . 
docker build -t bitplan/dataexample:0.0.1 .
```

builds these images

and they both show in my images list now:

```
docker images | grep data

wf@mars:~/source/docker/stackoverflow2>    docker images | grep data
bitplan/dataonly          0.0.1               aa6aeb923f55        9 minutes ago       188.4 MB
bitplan/dataexample       0.0.1               a005e6b7dd01        7 days ago          188.4 MB
```

running and testing is done with

```
docker run -d --name html bitplan/dataonly:0.0.1
docker run --volumes-from html bitplan/dataexample:0.0.1 ls /var/www/html
```

which shows:

```
0ebb78f209169fb7d281bb6b06851b33af7a98488c3a38cf25ac92fe983fff43
file1.html
file2.html
index.html
```

Comment: This link 404's for me: 
 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E54669/html/section_ffp_yt4_gp.html  That's too bad.  I'd like to see the original example.

Answer (score 9):

It's very simple. You have to share one directory to two different containers, then have both access to the same data in that directory.

```
docker run -v myfolder:/data/myfolder image-name-1
docker run -v myfolder:/data/myfolder image-name-2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I have an application running inside one container which will generate some files in directory. Your solution is host ==> container1 and host ==> container. What I want is container1 ==> container2

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just use the `--volumes-from` to mount 2 or more volumes from one container to one another
Dockerfile1

```
FROM alpine:3.7

MAINTAINER john "john@gmail.com"

ENV REFRESHED_AT=2021-02-01 \

VOLUME ["/mount1", "/mount2"]

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]

EXPOSE 80
```

Dockerfile2

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

MAINTAINER john "john@gmail.com"

ENV REFRESHED_AT=2021-02-01 \

VOLUME ["/mount1", "/mount2"]

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]

EXPOSE 80
```

You build 2 of them, then you create the first container by creating a folder in or outside the Dockerfile. For the second container, you just need to issue this attribute `--volumes-from <first container>`. This method means that the second container will mount 2 mountpoint from the first container to the second container.