# Accessing data in mounted Docker Volumes running in the Jenkins Docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins but have some experience running docker. I have setup the Jenkins Docker container to run as a privileged root user as follows

`docker run -u root --privileged -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 --restart=on-failure -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11`

Within the container (exec bash) I have added some custom configurations

```
apt update
apt install docker.io
git config --global --add safe.directory "*"
```

My Jenkinsfile is

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image "docker"
        }
    }
    environment {
        CODECOV_TOKEN = "50dd5c2e-4259-4cfa-97a7-b4429e0d179e"
        CONTAINER_SUFFIX = "${BUILD_NUMBER}"
        DOCKER_NETWORK = "variantvalidator_docker_network-$CONTAINER_SUFFIX"
    }
    stages {
        stage("Clone Repository and Create Docker Network") {
            steps {
                checkout scm
                sh 'docker network create $DOCKER_NETWORK'
            }
        }
        stage("Create Directories on Host") {
            steps {
                sh 'mkdir /var/jenkins_home/workspace/VariantValidator_ci/variantvalidator_data'
                sh 'mkdir /var/jenkins_home/workspace/VariantValidator_ci/variantvalidator_data/share'
                sh 'mkdir /var/jenkins_home/workspace/VariantValidator_ci/variantvalidator_data/share/seqrepo/'
                sh 'mkdir /var/jenkins_home/workspace/VariantValidator_ci/variantvalidator_data/share/logs'
            }
        }
        stage("Where am I") {
            steps {
                sh 'pwd'
                sh 'ls -l'
            }
        }
        stage("Build and Run VVTA PostgreSQL") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def dockerfile = './db_dockerfiles/vvta/Dockerfile'
                    def vvtaContainer = docker.build("postgres-vvta-${CONTAINER_SUFFIX}", "-f ${dockerfile} ./db_dockerfiles/vvta")
                    vvtaContainer.run("-p 5432:5432 -d --name vvta --network $DOCKER_NETWORK")
                    sh 'echo Building and running VVTA PostgreSQL'
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Build and Run Validator MySQL") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def dockerfile = './db_dockerfiles/vdb/Dockerfile'
                    def validatorContainer = docker.build("mysql-validator-${CONTAINER_SUFFIX}", "-f ${dockerfile} ./db_dockerfiles/vdb")
                    validatorContainer.run("-p 3306:3306 -d --name vdb --network $DOCKER_NETWORK")
                    sh 'echo Building and running Validator MySQL'
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Build and Run SeqRepo") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def dockerfile = './db_dockerfiles/vvsr/Dockerfile'
                    def seqRepoContainer = docker.build("sqlite-seqrepo-${CONTAINER_SUFFIX}", "-f ${dockerfile} ./db_dockerfiles/vvsr")
                    seqRepoContainer.run("--network $DOCKER_NETWORK --privileged -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/VariantValidator_ci/variantvalidator_data/share:/usr/local/share:rw -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/VariantValidator_ci/variantvalidator_data/share/seqrepo:/usr/local/share/seqrepo:rw -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/VariantValidator_ci/variantvalidator_data/share/logs:/usr/local/share/logs:rw -d")
                    sh 'echo Building and running SeqRepo'
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Find Seqrepo Mount") {
            steps {
                sh 'pwd'
                sh 'ls -l'
                sh 'ls -l /var/jenkins_home/workspace/VariantValidator_ci/variantvalidator_data/share/seqrepo/'
            }
        }
        stage("Build and Run VariantValidator") {
            steps {
                script {
                    def dockerfile = './Dockerfile'
                    def variantValidatorContainer = docker.build("variantvalidator-${CONTAINER_SUFFIX}", "-f ${dockerfile} .")
                    variantValidatorContainer.run("--privileged -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/VariantValidator_ci/variantvalidator_data/share:/usr/local/share:rw -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/VariantValidator_ci/variantvalidator_data/share/logs:/usr/local/share/logs:rw -v /var/jenkins_home/workspace/VariantValidator_ci/variantvalidator_data/share/seqrepo:/usr/local/share/seqrepo:rw -d --name variantvalidator-${CONTAINER_SUFFIX} --network $DOCKER_NETWORK")
                    sh 'echo Building and running VariantValidator'
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Run Pytest and Codecov") {
            steps {
                sh 'docker ps'
                sh 'docker exec variantvalidator-${CONTAINER_SUFFIX} pytest --cov-report=term --cov=VariantValidator/'
                sh 'docker exec variantvalidator-${CONTAINER_SUFFIX} codecov'
            }
        }
        stage("Cleanup Docker") {
            steps {
                sh 'docker stop vvta'
                sh 'docker rm vvta'
                sh 'docker stop vdb'
                sh 'docker rm vdb'
                sh 'docker stop sqlite-seqrepo-${CONTAINER_SUFFIX}'
                sh 'docker rm sqlite-seqrepo-${CONTAINER_SUFFIX}'
                sh 'docker stop variantvalidator-${CONTAINER_SUFFIX}'
                sh 'docker rm variantvalidator-${CONTAINER_SUFFIX}'
                sh 'docker network rm $DOCKER_NETWORK'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I have assed a couple of ls commands to help with debugging. When I run the build and test, everything sets up and installs, but the volume mounting is not functioning as expected. The data build in stage("Build and Run SeqRepo") is not accessible from the main container, so cannot be mounted further along in the workflow.

The log shows (cropped)

```
+ mkdir /var/jenkins_home/workspace/VariantValidator_ci/variantvalidator_data
[Pipeline] sh
+ mkdir /var/jenkins_home/workspace/VariantValidator_ci/variantvalidator_data/share
[Pipeline] sh
+ mkdir /var/jenkins_home/workspace/VariantValidator_ci/variantvalidator_data/share/seqrepo/
[Pipeline] sh
+ mkdir /var/jenkins_home/workspace/VariantValidator_ci/variantvalidator_data/share/logs
[Pipeline] { (Where am I)
[Pipeline] sh
+ pwd
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/VariantValidator_ci
[Pipeline] sh
+ ls -l
total 116
.......
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 Sep 11 10:20 variantvalidator_data
```

so I'm happy the directories are being created

The stage("Build and Run SeqRepo") runs and creates the data. The container keeps running.

However the ls of the volume mount suggests that the data cannot be accessed

```
+ ls -l /var/jenkins_home/workspace/VariantValidator_ci/variantvalidator_data/share/seqrepo/
total 0
```

I have used "rw" in the mount commands. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

I would expect to see directories and files when the ls command is run

This issue suggests a solution, but I am not clear what to do with the information. Same for other relates issues. Hope to write a complete solution here

Comment: This issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42946067/how-to-mount-docker-volume-with-jenkins-docker-container suggests a possible route to the solution, but I am not clear how to make it work from what has been posted. Same for other potential suggestions. Hope to write a clear answer here

Comment: "Within the container (exec bash)" is making temporary-only changes that will be lost as soon as the container exits.  Do these need to go into a Dockerfile so that they'll be part of a persistent image?  It looks like you're spelling out a full `/var/jenkins_home/...` directory path; does the environment variable `$WORKSPACE` work better?  (Jenkins will automatically bind-mount it into the build container for you.)

Comment: That certainly tidied things up @DavidMaze but still having the same issue. Seems to be something to do with the use of --volumes-from while reading around. In my log I see

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker:latest
docker.io/library/docker:latest
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins seems to be running inside container 68f14771d7904ba66ddc79ab8d20fac1f3957edf4999270626058f1d2205a570
$ docker run -t -d -u 0:0 -w /var/jenkins_home/workspace/VariantValidator_ci --volumes-from 68f14771d7904ba66ddc79ab8d20fac1f3957edf4999270626058f1d2205a570 
```